Removing duplicate data based on multiple attributes
I have a table created using tabulate intersection in ArcGIS Pro, that denotes the species records within each grid cell at certain resolutions e.g.



Cell ID
Taxon Name
Grid Precision (m)




1
Erodium circutarium
1


1
Erodium circutarium
100


1
Aphanes australis
100


2
Erodium circutarium
1


2
Festuca filiformis
1000


2
Festuca filiformis
1000


2
Aira pracecox
2000



I want to remove duplicates where ID, taxon name and grid precision are the same (row 5&6). But also where ID and taxon name are the same, I want the higher grid precision to be removed (row 1&2) e.g. for the top two rows, I only want grid precision of 1m to be remaining.
So the final table would look like this:



Cell ID
Taxon Name
Grid Precision (m)




1
Erodium circutarium
1


1
Aphanes australis
100


2
Erodium circutarium
1


2
Festuca filiformis
1000


2
Aira pracecox
2000



I have had a look at removing duplicates but because it involves multiple attributes I am a bit stuck on which method will get me the results. Happy to work with Python or SQL in ArcGIS Pro or Excel (or another program if necessary).

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour] , which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Asking for solutions in multiple languages or platforms  is, in effect, multiple questions. The most frequent comments here are "What have you tried?" and "Where are you stuck?" If your Question doesn't address thesr, it is likely to be closed. Even ignoring non-spatial tools like Excel, you have a number of noncodong solutions available within Pro (Dissolve, Frequency, Summary Statistics). Choose one, or Python, or shudder Excel, try it, then describe any problem

Sort by ascending order using precision field , and use delete identical using other fields

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-and-remove-duplicates-00e35bea-b46a-4d5d-b28e-66a552dc138d can help you in MS Excel.

This can be done with a Dissolve if the features have geometries. If it is a table without geometries use Summary Statistics (Analysis).

Dissolve- or Case Field are Cell ID and Taxon Name
Statistics Fields should be like min(Grid Precision)

